# SQL Query to find MAX Date

Tags: sql, dbase

I have some software that uses dBase4 for its database. I am attempting to construct a report using fields from 3 tables (Customer, Service & History).

In all of the tables the ACCOUNT field is the same. The 'Customer' and the 'Service' table only have one one record for each Customer. The 'History' table has multiple records for each Customer.

I need to write a query so that only the record with the MAX date in 'History.BILLTHRU' is returned for each Customer. The code below returns all of the records for each Customer in the History table:

```
SELECT Customer.ACCOUNT, 
       Customer.FIRSTNAME, 
       (more fields...), 
       History.ACCOUNT, 
       History.BILLTHRU, 
       Service.ACCOUNT, 
       Service.OFFERCODE

FROM "C:\Customer.dbf" Customer

INNER JOIN "C:\History.dbf" History 
ON (Customer.ACCOUNT = History.ACCOUNT)

INNER JOIN "C:\Service.dbf" Service 
ON (Customer.ACCOUNT = Service.ACCOUNT) 

WHERE Customer.STATUS = "A" 
ORDER BY Customer.LAST_BUS_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-query and a group by:

```
SELECT Customer.ACCOUNT, 
       Customer.FIRSTNAME, 
       (more fields...), 
       History.ACCOUNT, 
       History.BILLTHRU, 
       Service.ACCOUNT, 
       Service.OFFERCODE

FROM "C:\Customer.dbf" Customer

INNER JOIN (SELECT ACCOUNT, MAX(BILLTHRU) AS BILLTHRU
            FROM "C:\History.dbf"
            GROUP BY ACCOUNT) History
ON (Customer.ACCOUNT = History.ACCOUNT)

INNER JOIN "C:\Service.dbf" Service 
ON (Customer.ACCOUNT = Service.ACCOUNT) 

WHERE Customer.STATUS = "A" 
ORDER BY Customer.LAST_BUS_NAME
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when I add your code as you wrote.

Comment: @dnevels - care to share what the error is and where you see it?

Comment: I don't know more specifically where the error is and the program on says it cannot execute the query, please check the syntax. The query i have above (with the fields added in place of the (more fields...)) runs without error. When I add your code as written is when I get the error. Your syntax is probably correct, could this have something to do with it being run in dBase?

Comment: @dnevels, are you still stuck on this answer?  I might suggest changing the "alias" of the subquery to "H2" as to not cause conflict with alias references, but other than that, the query looks fine.  Also use the "H2" reference in the select fields list.  It might be getting an ambiguous which "Account / BillThru" do you want as the raw History table will be open when the query is processed.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use common table expressions [(CTEs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). Subqueries are good, but breaking it out like this sometimes makes it easier to keep separate.

```
with GetMaxDate as (

select account, max(billthru) as MaxBillThru
       from  "C:\History.dbf"
       group by account
)

SELECT Customer.ACCOUNT, 
       Customer.FIRSTNAME, 
       (more fields...), 
       GetMaxDate.ACCOUNT, 
       GetMaxDate.MaxBillThru,
       Service.ACCOUNT, 
       Service.OFFERCODE
       .....
from FROM "C:\Customer.dbf" Customer

INNER JOIN GetMaxDate on customer.ACCOUNT = GetMaxDate.Account
INNER JOIN "C:\Service.dbf" Service 
ON (Customer.ACCOUNT = Service.ACCOUNT) 

WHERE Customer.STATUS = "A" 
ORDER BY Customer.LAST_BUS_NAME
```

EDIT: This is a SQL Server function. I'm leaving it in case it can help you or someone else. I'll delete it if it just clouds the issue.